# GUID to ByteArray

Tags: java, guid, arrays, uuid

I just wrote this code to convert a GUID into a byte array.  Can anyone shoot any holes in it or suggest something better?

```
 public static byte[] getGuidAsByteArray(){

 UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
 long longOne = uuid.getMostSignificantBits();
 long longTwo = uuid.getLeastSignificantBits();

 return new byte[] {
      (byte)(longOne >>> 56),
      (byte)(longOne >>> 48),
      (byte)(longOne >>> 40),
      (byte)(longOne >>> 32),   
      (byte)(longOne >>> 24),
      (byte)(longOne >>> 16),
      (byte)(longOne >>> 8),
      (byte) longOne,
      (byte)(longTwo >>> 56),
      (byte)(longTwo >>> 48),
      (byte)(longTwo >>> 40),
      (byte)(longTwo >>> 32),   
      (byte)(longTwo >>> 24),
      (byte)(longTwo >>> 16),
      (byte)(longTwo >>> 8),
      (byte) longTwo
       };
}
```

In C++, I remember being able to do this, but I guess theres no way to do it in Java with the memory management and all?:

```
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

    long[] longArray = new long[2];
    longArray[0] = uuid.getMostSignificantBits();
    longArray[1] = uuid.getLeastSignificantBits();

    byte[] byteArray = (byte[])longArray;
    return byteArray;
```

### Edit

If you want to generate a completely random UUID as bytes that does not conform to any of the official types, this will work and wastes [10 fewer bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier) than type 4 UUIDs generated by UUID.randomUUID():

```
    public static byte[] getUuidAsBytes(){
    int size = 16;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
    new Random().nextBytes(bytes);
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055413 ?

Comment: No, I was mentioning that in C++, you could have skipped having to copy everything into another array, but it doesn't look like you can do that in Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending a Java UUID to C++ as bytes and back over TCP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055413/sending-a-java-uuid-to-c-as-bytes-and-back-over-tcp)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I would rely on built in functionality:

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[16]);
bb.putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
bb.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
return bb.array();
```

or something like,

```
ByteArrayOutputStream ba = new ByteArrayOutputStream(16);
DataOutputStream da = new DataOutputStream(ba);
da.writeLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
da.writeLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
return ba.toByteArray();
```

(Note, untested code!)

Comment: It does not give the same UUID when I call UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(bb.array());

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay that's to be expected, nameUUIDFromBytes takes a hash from the bytes you pass to it. to deserialize the format above read the longs again and use the constructor UUID(long,long)

Answer (score 15):

```
public static byte[] newUUID() {
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    long hi = uuid.getMostSignificantBits();
    long lo = uuid.getLeastSignificantBits();
    return ByteBuffer.allocate(16).putLong(hi).putLong(lo).array();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check [`UUID`](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/id/apidocs/org/apache/commons/id/uuid/UUID.html) from apache-commons. You may not want to use it, but check the [sources](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/sandbox/id/trunk/src/java/org/apache/commons/id/uuid/UUID.java) to see how its `getRawBytes()` method is implemented:

```
public UUID(long mostSignificant, long leastSignificant) {
    rawBytes = Bytes.append(Bytes.toBytes(mostSignificant), Bytes.toBytes(leastSignificant));
}
```

Comment: sorry for commenting on old post. but why not use this : uuid.toString().getBytes()

Comment: and how you should convert the byte[] to mostSignificat and leastSignificatnt in order to regenerate the original uuid?

Comment: `uuid.toString().getBytes()` builds a byte[] containing the byte representation of the system's default string encoding of the textual representation of the UUID. So, probably the UTF-8 bytes that represent a string like `37B4C0FB-6BEB-4EEF-8D4F-5552C3C76952`. That's 36 bytes long. On the other hand, the proposed solution is just two `long`s, or 128 bits, or 16 bytes. So, 44% of the space.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at Apache Commons Lang3 [Conversion.uuidToByteArray(...)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/Conversion.html#uuidToByteArray-java.util.UUID-byte:A-int-int-). Conversely, look at [Conversion.byteArrayToUuid(...)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/Conversion.html#byteArrayToUuid-byte:A-int-) to convert back to a UUID.