# Java / .NET implementation of deterministic GUID/UUID generation

Tags: java, .net, guid, uuid

I am trying to replicate the following .NET code in Java

https://github.com/LogosBible/Logos.Utility/blob/master/src/Logos.Utility/GuidUtility.cs

I have written equivalent code in Java but I get different values for the final GUID/UUID

Changes I made for Java - 
To convert the UUID to the byte array (Step 3 in the code above) I used the following - [GUID to ByteArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983065/guid-to-bytearray)

```
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[16]);
    bb.putLong(namespaceId.getMostSignificantBits());
    bb.putLong(namespaceId.getLeastSignificantBits());
    byte[] namespaceBytes = bb.array()
```

For the hashing part ( Step 4) i use apache-commons message-digest class

```
    final MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(namespaceBytes);
    outputStream.write(nameBytes);
    sha.update(outputStream.toByteArray());
    final byte[] hash = sha.digest();
```

The rest of the code is completely the same.

However after going through the other questions posted here about Java's signed byte array and .NET's unsigned byte. I have logged the output I get at each point and I dont see any similarity in the outputs at both these steps.

After reading through a few threads, Ive realized that the GUID.toByteArray() method works differently from the way I am converting the value in java. Also the byte array in .NET is unsigned, a type which is not supported in Java. How can I fix the code to get it to work for Java?

Comment: I think you picked the wrong stack overflow answer to base your work on. This one is more relevant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745512/how-to-read-a-net-guid-into-a-java-uuid